# How to set MenuSelect value to a boolean in a Formik form?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik, formik-material-ui

I'm working in a Formik form and I have a very simple material UI Select dropdown list:

```
<FormControlLabel 
     control={
        (
          <Field component={Select} type="checkbox" name="isFoundationalSupport">
               <MenuItem value="yes">Yes</MenuItem>
               <MenuItem value="no">No</MenuItem>
               <MenuItem value="null">Unknown</MenuItem>
           </Field>
         )
      }
      label="Foundational support"
      labelPlacement="top"
 />
```

For the three menu items, I would like the values to be true, false, or null but those are not acceptable values for the value field in MenuItem. Is my only route to use component state? I was hoping to keep it simple and stick with Formik state and values but not sure that's possible in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `MenuItem`'s prop `value` only accepts string or number, you'll have to convert it in an `onChange` handler.

You don't need any extra state to perform this, you can simply use formik's function `setFieldValue()`.

```
// define all the options
const selectOptions = [
  { id: true, text: "Yes" },
  { id: false, text: "No" },
  { id: null, text: "Unknown" }
];

// and in the component
<FormControlLabel
  control={
    <Field
      component={Select}
      placeholder="Select One"
      type="checkbox"
      value={
        selectOptions.find(
          ({ id }) => id === values.isFoundationalSupport
        ).text
      }
      name="isFoundationalSupport"
      onChange={(e) => {
        if (e.target.value) {
          const { id } = selectOptions.find(
            ({ text }) => text === e.target.value
          );
          setFieldValue("isFoundationalSupport", id);
        }
      }}
    >
      {selectOptions.map(({ text }) => (
        <MenuItem key={text} value={text}>
          {text}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </Field>
  }
  label="Foundational support"
  labelPlacement="top"
/>
```

[Working Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-material-ui-and-yup-forked-4ks7e?file=/src/form/Form.js:510-1481)

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much. My app was crashing initially with the .text on the value when 'Unknown' was chosen ("Cannot find .text of undefined") so I changed the id from null to undefined and gave me exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again!